# Cannot detect HP SB40c RAID controller in ACU

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant

Our small business has been running a BL460c Gen6 in a c7000 enclosure for a few months, but we need more storage. We purchased a refurbished SB40c and drives. The issue is that while I  **can**  detect the Sb40c's raid controller in the BIOS, I cannot see it in ACU to configure the raid.

Also, when booting to Windows Server 2012 R2 on the BL460c while the SB40c is inserted I get a BSOD with WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR and cannot boot into Windows.

The BL460c Gen 6 has a HP Smart Array p410i with two drives in RAID 1.
The SB40c has a HP Smart Array p400 that I plan on running in RAID 5.

I'm pretty new with servers and any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Silly question but what slot number is the BL460c G6 in and what slot number is the SB40c in?

Comment: @Chopper3 BL460c is in slot 1 and SB40c is in Slot 2. The OA sees the SB40c as a partner blade to the BL460c, so I'm pretty sure I have at least that right lol.

Comment: Odd - wonder if there's something broken in the SB40c? I have about forty or so D2220sb's and recently had one semi-die in-life, it wasn't very clear it was that that had died.

Comment: @Chopper3 This is a replacement as I thought the first one was defective, as well. The p400 is lacking a cache module. Could that cause an issue?